# Detect U-shave or V-shape in data series

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have a data series. I need to find all data segments that look look like U-shape or V-shape. Using the data below as an example, if I define the U-shape or V-shape as starting and ending point with ratio>=0.7 and all points in between are with ratio<0.7 and at least one point in between with ratio<=0.2. With this requirements, I can say two segments in this sample data (12/18/2021 to 12/22/2021, and 12/24/2021 to 12/27/2021) are with U or V shape.

is there some easy way to do this in python or with any package other than writing loops to identify the starting point and nested loop to identify the ending point? Thanks.

| date | ratio |
| --- | --- |
| 12/12/2021 | 0.676 |
| 12/13/2021 | 0.66 |
| 12/14/2021 | 0.682 |
| 12/15/2021 | 0.815 |
| 12/16/2021 | 0.784 |
| 12/17/2021 | 0.649 |
| 12/18/2021 | 0.859 |
| 12/19/2021 | 0.084 |
| 12/20/2021 | 0.156 |
| 12/21/2021 | 0.435 |
| 12/22/2021 | 0.741 |
| 12/23/2021 | 0.671 |
| 12/24/2021 | 0.761 |
| 12/25/2021 | 0.391 |
| 12/26/2021 | 0.126 |
| 12/27/2021 | 0.8 |
| 12/28/2021 | 0.761 |
| 12/29/2021 | 1.025 |
| 12/30/2021 | 0.776 |
| 12/31/2021 | 0.849 |

Comment: It would be good if you could write what you have attempted so far, and what didn't work

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question itself, instead you should post an answer

Comment: @sguo I agree with Abdul, your answer deserves to be up here as an answer. In my opinion, your answer should be the accepted answer to the question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a function as below to do it. flag==1 means the point is part of a U-shape.

```
def U_sahpe_detect(df):
    df.sort_values('date', inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    ct=df.shape[0]
    flag=[0]*ct

    # first pass loop from earliest to latest dates
    for idx in range(ct):
        if df.loc[idx, 'ratio']<=0.2:
            flag[idx]=1
        elif idx>0 and df.loc[idx, 'ratio']<0.7 and flag[idx-1]==1:
        flag[idx]=1
        
    # 2nd pass loop from latest to earliest dates
    for idx in range(ct-1, -1, -1):            
        if flag[idx]==1:
            continue           
        elif idx<ct-1 and df.loc[idx, 'ratio']<0.7 and flag[idx+1]==1:
            flag[idx]=1

    df['flag']=flag
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Start at all points `ratio <= 0.2` and grow the neighborhood until the endpoints are both `>=0.7`.

So there are 2 V's with the minimum at:

```
12/20/2021  0.156
12/26/2021  0.126
```

This is a 1-d variant (or conceptual cousin) of the watershed algorithm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)

##### GAME OF LIFE

So you can implement this similar to a game of life or cellular automata. First mark all data points `<= 0.2` as blue. Every round implement this rule for each data point. If any neighbor is blue and < 0.7 or if I'm already blue => I'm blue else I'm black. Iterate rounds until no data point changes color.

Second, find each continuous range of blue data points. That range is a "V-shape".

Comment: Thanks @SargeATM. I write a function in the spirit of your suggestion. I will update my question with my code samples